# SOLR API - modifying the schema for one collection modifies it for ALL collections

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR Server with several collections.

To retrieve the properties of the fields, I ran these requests:

- `GET http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection_id_1>/schema/fields`
- `GET http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection_id_2>/schema/fields`

Then I ran a `POST http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection_id_1>/schema` request, with the content needed to change some fields properties.

After this, I noticed that **the same fields properties changes were also modified for** `collection_id_2`.

Is this normal behaviour ?
What did I do wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection [uses a configset for its configuration](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/config-sets.html). This configset will be shared across multiple collections, unless you've explicitly [made a copy when you created the collection](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/configsets-api.html#configsets-create) or you're not defining a specific configset at all (in that case one will be created for you from the `_default` configset - depending on your Solr version).